# CloudKit NSPredicate case insensitive

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I have a cloud kit query that uses the NSPredicate below to search for records where the name begins with the value the user enters into the `UITextField`. I would like to make the search case insensitive so if the user searched for "apple" it would display results for "Apple" and "apple".
How can I do this? I have also tried to change the query to `CONTAINS` instead of `BEGINSWITH` but the app returns no results as it is looking for the value in an array. Is it possible to see if the string contains the text field string?
Thanks

```
var p = NSPredicate(format: "name BEGINSWITH %@", titleLabel.text!)
```

Comment: `BEGINSWITH[c]` ? "String comparisons are, by default, case and diacritic sensitive. You can modify an operator using the key characters c and d within square braces to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively, for example firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] $FIRST_NAME." from https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1 (String Comparisons section)

Comment: Is the `$FIRST_NAME` where I should place `titleLabel.text!`?

Comment: `"name BEGINSWITH[c] %@"` is what you should do.

Comment: When I add that it crashes on the line where the `NSPredicate` is added to the `CKQuery`. This is the line: `let q = CKQuery(recordType: "Content", predicate: p)`

Comment: If it crashes, what's the error message?

Comment: It just says `(lldb) `

Comment: Is there any way I can find more helpful information?

Comment: I don't think you can do a case insensitive search with a CloudKit predicate. CloudKit predicates use only a subset of what's possible with NSPredicate. You could use a workaround where you create a new field called nameSearch and duplicates the data there in lowercase. Then you can do a lowercase search in that field.

Comment: Okay. I will have a look in to that idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `CKQuery` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckquery#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKQuery):

> For fields that contain string values, you can match the beginning
>   portion of the string using the BEGINSWITH operator as shown in
>   Listing 4. You cannot use other string comparison operators such as
>   CONTAINS or ENDSWITH. When using this operator, the field must contain
>   a string value and must start with the string you specified. **Matches
>   are case sensitive.** In the examples, the predicate matches records
>   whose favoriteColors field contained the strings red, reddish, or red
>   green duct tape.

Comment: It is correct that BEGINSWITH is case sensitive. However you can use a query on self with 

     NSPredicate(format: "self contains %@", NSString(string: name))

Then it is case insensitive. Make sure you mark it for querying etc in the dashboard.